# is there a way to completely disable the SoftKeyboard in Android Application?

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

I am in the process of creating a wrapper application for a web-app in order to use a mobile handheld with scanner to scan barcodes and submit it to the website.

The site containing HTML input fields that are automatically focues in order to capture data from the scanner.
However, everytime this field focuses, the android soft keyboard is shown and the business does not want this behaviour.

I found a way to programmatically hide and show the keyboard using the following code:

```kotlin
val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
//show the keyboard
imm.showSoftInput(webview, 0)
//hide the keyboard
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(webview.windowToken, 0)
```

however, as soon as I click into an input field, the keyboard reopens again.
Unfortunately, the source of the html page cannot be changed, so my idea was to use a button in the actionBar to disable/toggle soft keyboard for the activity.

Is there a way (if yes: how?) to archieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`webview.isFocusableInTouchMode = false`

Eg : -

```
    webview.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    webview.isFocusableInTouchMode = false
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Comment: i tried it, but unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: Is that possible for you to share the link you are using for webview?

Answer (score -1):

Close soft keyboard：

```kotlin
 private fun closeKeyBroad() {
        val imm = activity?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
        activity?.currentFocus?.let { softKeyBroadView ->
            if (imm?.isActive == true && softKeyBroadView.windowToken != null) {
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(softKeyBroadView.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this in your activity's onCreate()

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM);`

Below is the documentation mentioned for the flag.

> Window flag: invert the state of {@link #FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE} with
> * respect to how this window interacts with the current method.  That
> * is, if FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE is set and this flag is set, then the
> * window will behave as if it needs to interact with the input method
> * and thus be placed behind/away from it; if FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE is
> * not set and this flag is set, then the window will behave as if it
> * doesn't need to interact with the input method and can be placed
> * to use more space and cover the input method.

Comment: Instead of simply giving negative marking can you add a comment on why this won't work with you?

Comment: Dear Vismay, I tried the code: if this was put in the onCreate method, the soft keyboard is disabled completely, however: it cannot be turned on again.
I want toggle the availability of the softkeyboard with a button in the actionbar.
If it put this into a function and call it when pressing the button, it won't work at all